# Minefieldin C matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I want to make a minefield. First I made a matrix, asked the user to enter with the rows and columns.

I need to:

1. put the bombs
2. indicate the amount of bombs nearby.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int rows, columns, i, j, bombs, **matrix;

    printf("\Enter the rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Enter the columns:");
    scanf("%d", &columns);
    printf("Enter the bombs:");
    scanf("%d", &bombs);

    if (bombs>= (rows*colums)){
        printf("Error");
    }
    if (bombs<= 0){
        printf("Error);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }  

    // show the map //

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            printf("%d", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }  
    return 0;
}
``
```

Comment: You don't appear to have actually stored any information in your matrix to indicate that random tiles actually have bombs, so I think you need to tackle that first.

Comment: If your matrix stores ints, and you'll eventually need to put 1, 2, or 3 into spots to indicate bombs, then I suggest picking some different value to indicate a bomb. Perhaps 4 or 5? Store that into your matrix and you'll know that location is a bomb.

Comment: Populating those 1, 2, and 3 values will rely on being able to find the values of all "neighbors" to a given location in the matrix.

Comment: `allocMatrix`? I suggest you store a `struct` array instead of an `int`. This makes it more expandable, like, `struct { int is_mine, is_revealed, distance; } **m;` or a bitfield.

Comment: Or use an enum to indicate the different states.

Comment: Shouldn't numbers 0 to 8 be reserved to indicate potential nearby bombs?

Comment: I think -1 as a bomb is a good idea.  So make a matrix with all zeros, stick -1 at all the random locations, then loop through the matrix and for every zero value calcuate the real value by looking nearby for -1.

Comment: @gorpe Yes, if you think about it, on the best case a cell will have no bombs nearby, thus 0. On the worst case there could be 8 bombs around a cell. Any number outside of that range will work to indicate a bomb. -1 is an option.

Comment: To avoid a hard time allocating a 2d matrix you could allocate a 1d matrix and then index it like a 2d matrix - something like this: https://onlinegdb.com/GNoutb6XHq as opposed to a 2d matrix version which would look like https://onlinegdb.com/vvJjPuzDb

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your question. Instead, if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. If there's still anything unclear in the given answers, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: While [edit]s to the question to provide clarification and/or additional information are encouraged, edits which change the question sufficiently to invalidate an already posted answer are not permitted. In fact, the consensus is that any user with [edit privileges](/help/privileges/edit) should revert such edits. I have done so here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Data Structures

Instead of using an `int` then remembering magical numbers like `-1` indicates a mine, it's more natural to say what these mean explicitly. Then you can change your mind or add to it without worrying about rewriting your whole programme. In the whole minefield, it's useless to have `int **m` without `cols` and `rows`. This interdependence is a sign that you should also package them in a structure to pass as one variable.

```
struct tile { unsigned nearby : 4, is_mine : 1, is_revealed : 1; };
struct map { size_t x, y; struct tile **tile; };
```

These definitions are very similar to what you had before, but they express the intent of the code much better.

### Arrays

I would forget your complicated `alocMatrix` and just use one allocation, but then you have to use `tiles[y * map->x + x]`. Personal preference; I think it's easier to have a constructor that returns one allocated block.

```
struct map { size_t x, y; struct tile *tile; };
...
if(!(map = malloc(sizeof *map + sizeof *tile * x * y)))
    { if(!errno) errno = ERANGE; return 0; }
...
map->tile = (struct tile *)(map + 1);
memset(map->tile, 0, sizeof *tile * x * y);
```

### Mines

A method of laying mines uniformly at random is to repeatedly choose a random tile, throwing out the tiles you've seen. Another method is to visit all the tiles and calculate the probability of each, `P(mines left / tiles left)`. It depends on the number of mines which will be faster.

```
const size_t x1 = map->x, y1 = map->y;
size_t x, y, squares = x1 * y1;
assert(map && mines < squares);
for(x = 0; x < x1; x++) {
    for(y = 0; y < y1; y++) {
        struct tile *tile = &map->tile[y * x1 + x];
        tile->is_revealed = 0;
        tile->is_mine = rand() < RAND_MAX / squares * mines;
        mines -= tile->is_mine;
        squares--;
    }
}
for(x = 0; x < x1; x++) for(y = 0; y < y1; y++)
    map->tile[y * x1 + x].nearby =
    (x && y && map->tile[(y-1) * x1 + (x-1)].is_mine) +
    ...
    (x && y < y1 - 1 && map->tile[(y+1) * x1 + (x-1)].is_mine);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using this function to place the bombs? Call it by passing the address of `m`. Keep in mind that marking the rest of the squares with the appropriate number has to happen after the bombs have been placed (and it shouldn't depend on a call to `rand`). Also, the map has to be initialized to avoid surprises.

```
void placeBombs(int*** map, int numOfRows, int numOfColumns, int numOfBombs)
{
    while (numOfBombs > 0) {
        int column = rand() % numOfColumns;
        int row = rand() % numOfRows;
        if ((*map)[row][column] != -1) {
            (*map)[row][column] = -1;
            --numOfBombs;
        }
        /* Else, if a bomb already exists in the cell,
         * we iterate without placing a bomb
         */
    }
}
```